# Android create drop menu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-menu, android-cardview

I'm trying to create button with drop menu near it. Something like on screenshot, but I'm not sure what I should use: `CardView` or something else. Please, give am an advise or code example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to create a custom menu first. Let it be like following. Lets name it `your_menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  

<item  
    android:id="@+id/one"  
    android:title="One"/>  

<item  
    android:id="@+id/two"  
    android:title="Two"/>  

<item  
    android:id="@+id/three"  
    android:title="Three"/>  

</menu>
```

Then on your activities button click should have a onClickListener like following

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

       @Override  
       public void onClick(View v) {  

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, your_main_button);// 
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, popup.getMenu());   
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
         public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Clicked item is : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
          return true;  
         }  
        });  

        popup.show();//showing popup menu  
       }  
      });
```